# Domain, range and zeros of $f(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{4x-x^2-y^2}}{x^2y^2-4xy^2+3y^2}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Given the following function with two variables:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\sqrt{4x-x^2-y^2}}{x^2y^2-4xy^2+3y^2}
\end{equation}
I need to find a) the domain for the above function.
Can anyone give me a hint on how to find the domain in f?

I already know that:
\begin{equation}
    dom f = \{ f(x,y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2\backslash(x^2y^2-4xy^2+3y^2=0) : \sqrt{4x-x^2-y^2} \geq 0 \}
\end{equation}
But of course this needs to be written in a more simpler form.
During class we solve simpler functions  like without fractions and roots, so I don't have anything that can help me.

After this I also need to find:

- b) zeros of the function
- c) Calculating Algebraically, the range of the function:
  \begin{equation}
  T(x,y) = \sqrt{4x-x^2-y^2}
  \end{equation}
- d) Extreme values of the function T

I'm of course not expecting the complete solution but something like a kick start.

Comment: Is the edit OK? The square root seems to have shifted to being the whole thing. That would make OP's suggested $dom f$ incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the edit amWhy. As I wasn't sure how to write the symbols correctly I tried to use letters. But you made it a lot clearer.

Comment: The title makes it seem like you're advertising for a Kickstarter campaign "Help me solve this university level math problem!".

Comment: You're welcome, @reaper.

Answer (score 2):

To find the zeros of the denominator, note that you can factor out $y^2$ leaving an expression in $x$.  The denominator is zero whenever $y^2=0$, which is $y=0$ or when that expression in $x$ is.  In your expression of $dom f$, you should not have the square root sign.  You need the stuff under the square root to be greater than or equal to zero.  What kind of curve is $4x-x^2-y^2$?  You should complete the square in $x$

Answer (score 2):

You factored your first equation correctly. Now determine which values of $y$, $x$, yield a zero denominator:  $$y^2(x-3)(x-1) = 0 \implies y = 0, \text{ or } x = 3, \text{ or } x = 1$$

So all ordered pairs of the form $(x, 0), (3, y), (1, y), \; x, y \in \mathbb R$  must be omitted from the domain. One way to see this is to note that the horizontal line $y = 0$ (i.e., the $x$-axis), and the vertical lines $x = 1, x = 3$ are thus excluded from $\mathbb R^2$.

Also, the second restriction does not require  $\sqrt{4x-x^2-y^2} \geq 0$ (though it certainly will be true, given the proper restriction on the argument). Rather, we need the *argument* of the square root to be greater than or equal to zero, in order for the *square root* of the argument to be defined. $$\begin{align} 4x - x^2 - y^2 \geq 0 & \iff -4x + x^2 + y^2\leq 0\\ &\iff  x^2 - 4x + 4 + y^2 \leq 4 \\ &\iff (x - 2)^2 + y^2\leq (2)^2\end{align}$$

Note that $$ (x - 2)^2 + y^2= (2)^2$$ is the equation of a circle of radius 2, centered at the point $(2, 0)$. So $$(x - 2)^2 + y^2\leq (2)^2$$ is the subset of $\mathbb R^2$ consisting of all points on and inside the circle.

So the domain will be equal to the portion of the plane on and inside circle (all points $(x, y)$ such that $(x - 2)^2 + y^2\leq (2)^2)$, and excluding the lines $y = 0, x=1, x=3$.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone give me a hint on how to find the domain in f?

You need to find all the values for which $x^2 y^2-4xy^2+3y^2$ is not equal to zero and $4x-x^2-y^2$ is positive or zero.

> zeros of the function

Well you just need to find where $\sqrt{4x-x^2-y^2}=0$, which is just where $4x-x^2-y^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints-kick start:

- $4x-x^2-y^2=4-(x-2)^2-y^2$
- $(x-2)^2+y^2=4$ is the equation of a circle
- $x^2y^2-4xy^2+3y^2=y^2((x-2)^2-1)=y^2(x-3)(x-1)$

Answer (score 0):

we have for the domian two cases
$4x-x^2-y^2\geq 0$ and $y^2(x^2-4x+3)>0$
or
$4x-x^2-y^2\le 0$ and $y^2(x^2-4x+3)<0$
note that $x^2-4x+3=0$ gives $x_1=1$ or $x_2=3$ and $4x-x^2-y^2=4-(y^2+(x-2)^2)$ thus we get for the first case
$4>y^2+(x-2)^2$ and $x>3$ and $y\neq 0$
or
$4>y^2+(x-2)^2$ and $x<1$ and $y \neq 0$
and for the second case
$(x-2)^2+y^2\geq 4$ and $y\neq 0$ and $1<x<3$
sorry i thougt the problem was  $\sqrt{\frac{4x-x^2-y^2}{x^2y^2-4xy^2+3y^2}}$
b) the zeros of our functions are $(x-2)^2+y^2=4$ and $y^2\neq 0$ and $x\neq 3$ and $x\neq 1$
c) we have to solve
$T_x=\frac{2-x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2-y^2}}=0$
and
$T_y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{4x-x^2-y^2}}=0$

a) for the domain we have $(x-2)^2+y^2\le 4$ and $y\neq 0$ and $x\neq 3$ and $x\neq 1$

Comment: why was i downvoted? it was not clear what the square root stated

Comment: Sorry for the unclear writing. AmWhy edited my post. It should be clearer now, no?